# Nginx proxy_pass SSL

Tags: ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have a wordpress website running on 1 server and the API for my mobile apps running on a different server. My domain.com points to the website server, and I have domain.com/api forwarded to my API server. I have SSL working for the website server but don't know how to set it up for the API server.

On the website server I have the follow nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    include snippets/ssl-domain.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /var/www/website;
    index index.php;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    ...

    location ^~ /api {
            proxy_pass http://IP_OF_API_SERVER;
    }
}
```

On the API server I have the follow nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    location /  {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

This configuration is working but I want to have SSL for the connections to my API.